# remove post-name from title in custom post type

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting, url-routing

I simply want two custom post type meta propertys to be the identifiers for the URL. I implements a solution but it just 404's

registering post type:

```
    final private static function register_post_types ()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Properties', 'post type general name', ' propertystreambootstrap' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Property', 'post type singular name', ' propertystreambootstrap' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Properties', 'admin menu', ' propertystreambootstrap' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Property', 'add new on admin bar', ' propertystreambootstrap' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'property', ' propertystreambootstrap' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Property', ' propertystreambootstrap' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Property', ' propertystreambootstrap' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Property', ' propertystreambootstrap' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Property', ' propertystreambootstrap' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Properties', ' propertystreambootstrap' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Properties', ' propertystreambootstrap' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Properties:', ' propertystreambootstrap' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No properties found.', ' propertystreambootstrap' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No properties found in Trash.', ' propertystreambootstrap' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Properties for your website.', ' propertystreambootstrap' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-building',
        'query_var'          => true,
        //'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'malta-property/%department%/%location%/%reference%' ),
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'malta-property/%location%/%reference%'),
    'has_archive' => 'about-cool-post-types',
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => false,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'post-thumbnails', 'thumbnail')
    );
    register_post_type( 'property', $args );

}
```

Url rewrites:

```
        final public static function url_rewrite()
    {
  global $wp_rewrite;
      $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%reference%', '([^&]+)', 'reference=');
      $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%location%', '([^&]+)', 'location=');
        return null;
    }
```

filter function:

```
final public static function permalink_structure ($permalink, $post, $leavename)
{
  if (false !== strpos($permalink, '%reference%')) {
    $reference = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'propertystream_agent_ref', true);
    $location = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'location');
    $location = str_replace('-cat', '', $location[0]->slug);
  //  die($location);
  //  $department = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'department');
    $rewritecode = array(
      '%reference%',
      '%location%',
    //  '%department%',
      $post->post_name,
    );

    $rewritereplace = array(
      $reference,
      $location,
    //  $department,
      $leavename? $post->post_name : '',
    );

    $permalink = str_replace($rewritecode, $rewritereplace, $permalink);
  }
  return $permalink;
}
```

This all generates the code I want but it just 404's - to get it to work I have to add $leavename = true in the filter function but that adds the postname to the URL and I do not want that.

Comment: What do you mean by identifiers?

Comment: @SagarBahadurTamang sorry I just mean that the meta propertys should be the elements of the url between slashes